# Entering text + simulate Enter key using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Image of form:*

[image: Image of form]

Hi, I have created a chrome extension that injects jquery actions in a form which has 2 input boxes and a login button. Hence after entering the text in input box of form enter key is a must or user should manually enter the text.

I have tried injecting the text value into input boxes followed by the login click but it didnt work as react listeners in the form are not triggered.

```
UI Input boxes
1. email input box

<input type="email" name="email" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="yours@example.com" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-label="Email" aria-invalid="false" value="" >

2. password input box

<input type="password" name="password" class="auth0-lock-input" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" value="" aria-label="Password" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="your password" >

3. Login button

<button class="auth0-lock-submit" name="submit" type="submit" aria-label="Log In" style="background-color: rgb(51, 107, 155); display: block;">
```

Comment: Please help with the above :(